# Most pythonic way of iterating list items into a nested dict

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a problem and I want to determine whether my approach is sound. Here is the idea:

I would be creating a primary dict called zip_codes, of which respective zipcodes (from a list) were the names of each of the nested dicts. Each would have keys for "members", "offices", "members per office"
It would look like this:

```
zips {
    90219: {
      "members": 120,
      "offices": 18,
      "membersperoffice": 28
    },
    90220: {
      "members": 423,
      "offices": 37,
      "membersperoffice": 16
    }
}
```

and so on and so forth.

I think I need to build the nested dicts, and then process several lists against conditionals, passing resulting values into the corresponding dicts on the fly (i.e. based on how many times a zip code exists in the list).

Is using nested dictionaries the most pythonic way of doing this? Is it cumbersome? Is there a better way?

Can someone drop me a hint about how to push key values into nested dicts from a loop? I've not been able to find a good resource describing what I'm trying to do (if this is, indeed, the best path).

Thanks.

:edit: a more specific example:

1. determine how many instances of a zipcode are in list called membersperzip
2. find corresponding nested dict with same name as zipcode, inside dict called zips
3. pass value to corresponding key, called "members"  (or whatever key)

:edit 2:

MadPhysicist requested I give code examples (I don't even know where to start with this one and I can't find examples. All I've been able to do thus far is:

```
area_dict = {}

area_dict = dict.fromkeys(all_areas, 0)  #make all of the zipscodes keys, add a zero in the first non-key index

dictkeys = list (area_dict.keys())
```

That gets me a dict with a bunch of zip codes as keys. I've discovered no way to iterate through a list and create nested dicts (yet). Hence the actual question.

Please don't dogpile me and do the usual stack overflow thing. This is not me asking anyone to do my homework. This is merely me asking someone to drop me a HINT.

:edit 3:

Ok. This is convoluted (my fault). Allow me to clarify further:

So, I have an example of what the nested dicts should look like. They'll start out empty, but I need to iterate through one of the zip code lists to create all the nested dicts... inside of zips.

This is a sample of the list that I want to use to create the nested dicts inside of the zips dict:

```
zips = [90272, 90049, 90401, 90402, 90403, 90404, 90291, 90292, 90290, 90094, 90066, 90025, 90064, 90073]
```

And this is what I want it to look like

```
zips {
    90272: {
      "members": ,
      "offices": ,
      "membersperoffice": 
    },
    90049: {
      "members": ,
      "offices": ,
      "membersperoffice": 
    }
}
```

....
etc, etc. ( creating a corresponding nested dict for each zipcode in the list)

After I achieve this, I have to iterate through several more zip code lists... and those would spit out the number of times a zip code appears in a given list, and then find the dict corresponding to the zip code in question, and append that value to the relevant key.

One I figure out the first part, I can figure this second part out on my own.

Thanks again. Sorry for any confusion.

Comment: Ok. I can show you what I have, but my problem is that I cannot find any examples of what I am looking to do, and I can find no example in the python documentation, either. This is why I'm asking for hints.... links... directions. I'm not asking for anyone to do this for me, kthanks.

Comment: What is the *input* you are trying to convert to the nested dictionary you’ve shown (which isn’t quite syntactically valid btw)? Please show a specific example.

Comment: First, you need to specify what the input looks like. Once you have that in hand, I suggest getting a piece of paper and a pencil and trying to describe **in words** the steps you need to take to get from that input to the nested dictionary that you want. While you shouldn't worry about precise Python syntax, you should keep in mind the tools you have available like `if` statements and `for` loops. If you use the words "for" and "if" in your description, it will help you know how to translate it into Python later.

Comment: If you still need help, please show us the exact input that you are trying to transform into your nested dictionaries.

Comment: @mkrieger1 I wouldn't be able to add all inputs at once. I would be iterating through a list of zipcodes... so [90210, 90212, 90213..], determining how many times that zipcode shows up in the list, and then passing that number to some key inside of the nested dict that corresponds to that zip. If that doesn't make sense, please let me know and I'll try to clarify.

Comment: What should be the result if the input were the list `[90210, 90212, 90213]`?

Comment: @mkrieger1 Those would be used to create the nested dicts inside of the zip dict. It would look like this: zips {
    90210 = {
      "members": ,
      "offices": ,
      "membersperoffice": 
    },
    90212 = {
      "members": ,
      "offices": ,
      "membersperoffice": 
    }

Comment: @mkrieger1 that cut the end off... but the goal is to take each zip and create a corresponding nested dict. I updated the question, if you want to take a look at it. Thank you for working through this with me.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice I updated the question. Please let me know if that helps?

Comment: That’s not a thing that can exist in Python. I’m assuming you mean `{90210: ...}` not `{90210 = ...}`, but still, the inner dictionaries need some values and you haven’t shown where they come from and in which form (they should be part of the input).

Comment: @mkrieger1 The values could be set to zero, initially. I can append values later. What I ultimately need is to be able to a) build a nested dicts from a list (they just need to be named the zipcode name), and b) pass in key values via iteration through a list.
Is it possible that python cannot do this?

Comment: @mkrieger1 and yes, that = syntax is wrong. It should be as you described.

Comment: It seems to me that you are missing some understanding of fundamental Python concepts. I strongly encourage you to work through the [official Python tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/) to fill in the gaps in your knowledge. The concepts that are described there, especially the section on dictionaries, will give you the fundamental tools that will allow you to solve problems like this on your own. You probably know enough to just skip to section 4 on flow control. That and section 5 on data structures are probably the most important for you right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
all_areas = [90219, 90220]

zips = {zipcode: code_members(zipcode) for zipcode in all_areas}

def code_members(zipcode):
    if zipcode == 90219:
        return dict(members=120, offices=18, membersperoffice=28)
    return dict(members=423, offices=37, membersperoffice=16)
```

---

> I think I need to build the nested dicts, and then process several
>   lists against conditionals, passing resulting values into the
>   corresponding dicts on the fly (**i.e. based on how many times a zip
>   code exists in the list**).

Using the above approach, if a `zipcode` appears multiple times in the `all_areas` list, the resulting `zip` dictionary will only contain one instance of the `zipcode`.

> Is using nested dictionaries the most pythonic way of doing this? Is
>   it cumbersome? Is there a better way?

May I suggest making a simple object that represents the value of each `zipcode`. Something simple like:

Using dataclass:

```
@dataclass.dataclass
class ZipProperties(object):
    members: int
    offices: int
    membersperoffice: int
```

Using named tuple:

```
ZipProperties = collections.namedtuple('ZipProperties', ['members', 'offices', 'membersperoffice'])
```

You can then change the `code_members` function to this:

```
def code_members(zipcode):
    if zipcode == 90219:
        return ZipProperties(120, 18, 28)
    return ZipProperties(423, 37, 16)
```

---

Addressing your concrete example:

1. determine how many instances of a zipcode are in list called membersperzip
2. find corresponding nested dict with same name as zipcode, inside dict called zips
3. pass value to corresponding key, called "members" (or whatever key)

```
membersperzip: typings.List[Tuple[int, int]] = [(90219, 54)]

for zip, members in membersperzip:
    for zipcode, props in zips.items():
        if zipcode == zip:
            props.members = members
```

Comment: Maybe I'm not seeing clearly what this code is doing... but, my issue is that I want to iterate through a list to create nested dicts, and then iterate through other lists to add key values. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: @j-grimwood And what exactly is the problem when you try to do that?

Comment: @j-grimwood when you say "iterate through a list to create nested dicts", you have to be more specific. What list are you iterating, the `all_areas` zipcode list or the `membersperzip` list?

Comment: @mkrieger1 The problem is this isn't related to the question I am asking, not that the code doesn't work as intended. I think I'm going to give up on SO, because I'm too poor at communicating what I need to do. lol. I deeply appreciate both you and smac89 helping me.

Comment: @j-grimwood Once you've figured it out, just ask again. You can ping me via this comment to the new question

Comment: @smac89 Cheers. The best way I can describe it is: I need to build a nested dictionary with a list... all the initial key values can be empty. But the nested dicts need to be named whatever each of the values inside of the list are... in this case, zip codes.
The goal is to be able to reference the dicts via zip code, so they can be searched for and manipulated in a loop.

Comment: @j-grimwood ok I might have jumped the gun on that one and went directly to the next part. In the first code snippet I have up there it is doing exactly what you said plus also updating the value of each nested dict by calling the `code_members` function. If you want just strictly what you just said in your comment, you can replace the line starting with `zips` with this one: `zips = {zipcode: {} for zipcode in all_areas}`. This will create nested dicts which are keyed by `zipcode`

Comment: @smac89 I appreciate this. After looking more closely, you had it all along. It's actually a pretty simple solution. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you to append it when you have the actual value instead of initializing dictionary with empty values for each key. You have list of keys and I do not see why you want to put all of them to the dictionary without having value in the first place.

```
zips = [90272, 90049, 90401, 90402, 90403, 90404, 90291, 90292, 90290, 90094, 90066, 90025, 90064, 90073]
zips_dict = {}
for a_zip in zips:
    if a_zip not in zips_dict:
        # Initialize proper value here for members etc.
        zips_dict[a_zip] = proper_value
```

If you insist to initialize `dict` with empty value for each keys, you could use this, which will also iterate through the `list` anyway but in `python` comprehension.

```
zips = [90272, 90049, 90401, 90402, 90403, 90404, 90291, 90292, 90290, 90094, 90066, 90025, 90064, 90073]
zips_dict = {
   x:{
       "members":None,
       "offices":None,
       "membersperoffice":None,
   } for x in zips
}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: The reason I suggested appending hollow values was because I need the dicts to exist, named by zipcode, in order to append the additional values. Your code is useful. I appreciate it.